# Loading a module fails the first time load() is called, but succeeds after

Tags: apache-flex, module

I have a Button that when clicked loads a Flex module in my AIR application.  However, occasionally the Module fails to load the first time the button is clicked, but it works the second time it's clicked.  When I debug it in the debugger the READY event is not fired so the remaining logic is never called.

```
var moduleInfo:IModuleInfo = ModuleManager.getModule(managedModule.url);
moduleInfo.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY, function(event:ModuleEvent):void {
    trace("ModuleEvent.READY called.");
});
moduleInfo.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.ERROR, function(event:ModuleEvent):void {
    trace("ModuleEvent.ERROR called.");
});
moduleInfo.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.SETUP, function(event:ModuleEvent):void {
    trace("ModuleEvent.SETUP called.");
});
moduleInfo.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.PROGRESS, function(event:ModuleEvent):void {
    trace("ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.");
});
moduleInfo.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.UNLOAD, function(event:ModuleEvent):void {
    trace("ModuleEvent.UNLOAD called.");
});
moduleInfo.load(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
```

The ApplicationDomain.currentDomain is needed to fix other issues, but having it there or removing it doesn't seem to make a difference.  Sometimes the modules just doesn't load.  The output is roughly as follows:

[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[SWF] MyStupidModule.swf - 342,932 bytes after decompression
[trace] ModuleEvent.SETUP called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.

Notice READY is never called, and neither is ERROR.  If I click the button again here is what is printed out:

[trace] ModuleEvent.SETUP called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.PROGRESS called.
[trace] ModuleEvent.READY called.

Any clues what could be causing this?  We are using Flex 3.6.0 AIR 2.6.019

Comment: Any particular reason you're using ModuleManager and not ModuleLoader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store reference somewhere in the owner class to the ModuleInfoProxy (IModuleInfo) - the instance that ModuleManager.getModule() returns for you, for example

```
class MyMainClass
{
           private var moduleInfo:IModuleInfo;
           public function load():void
           {
                 moduleInfo = ModuleManager.getModule("SimpleModule.swf");
                 ...
           }    
}
```

ModuleInfoProxy uses weak reference events and GC can remove it completely with event handlers if the object has no more reference to it. Storing a reference to IModuleInfo in a local variable makes that object eligible for GC once the load() method exits.  If that happens before the module has fully loaded your listeners wouldn't be called back.

Comment: I think this actually might be the answer.  Thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 1):

This was an actual bug that was fixed in the SDK

http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-14669

Try updating to the most recent compatible SDK and you should be set.  It should be fixed in the SDK you have listed, but won't hurt.

If it doesn't work for you, I'll help you craft a work around.

Good news is you aren't crazy, it's a framework bug.

=)

Comment: I'm using 3.6 the bug you posted says 3.4 was the SDK it fixed in.  Wouldn't I already have the fix?  I'm also not using RSLs does this matter to manifest this bug?